# how can we merge two dataframe without losing any row in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe as below.

df1:

```
Student_Name,total
X,400
Y,350
D,450
E,420
```

df2:

```
Student_Name,jan
X,350               
Y,380
A,360
B,370
Y,380
```

output:

```
Student_Name,jan,feb
X,350,400               
Y,380,350
A,360,0
B,370,0
Y,380,350
```

output should have no. of row from df2, and value taken from df1. if df2 row label not found in df1 then there should be 0. also if df2 index column have duplicate . for example here Y is two times and both times we taken value for it from df1. also output should not have row which is not in df2 but in df1. here D and E is in df1 but not in df2 so don't include in output dataframe.

Comment: feb is column label and value taken from df1.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [pd.merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method:

```
In [38]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Student_Name', how='left').fillna(0)
Out[38]:
  Student_Name  total    jan
0            X    400  350.0
1            Y    350  380.0
2            Y    350  380.0
3            D    450    0.0
4            E    420    0.0
```

or:

```
In [39]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Student_Name', how='right').fillna(0)
Out[39]:
  Student_Name  total  jan
0            X  400.0  350
1            Y  350.0  380
2            Y  350.0  380
3            A    0.0  360
4            B    0.0  370
```

If you need to join only one column, then it might be faster to use `.map()` method:

```
In [47]: df2['new'] = df2.Student_Name.map(df1.set_index('Student_Name')['total']) \
                         .fillna(0).astype(int)

In [48]: df2
Out[48]:
  Student_Name  jan  new
0            X  350  400
1            Y  380  350
2            A  360    0
3            B  370    0
4            Y  380  350
```

Comment: Worth also noting: this can be surprisingly slow (compared to a typical pandas operation) and funny things happen with types since the fill value has to be a float.

Comment: @pvg, thank's for your comment. I've added an alternative solution - it should be faster compared to `merge()`

Comment: Also check for duplicate keys. Duplicates may, potentially, lead to big problems

Comment: @AsheKetchum, IMO in order to be able to take care of duplicates - we should first know what OP wants to do with them...

Comment: @MaxU That is a very good point. :) I just wanted to comment on the nature of the `merge()` function provided by pandas.